# installed printer Samsung CLX-3185FW on Ubuntu 12.04. Printer not responding

Tags: drivers, printing, software-installation, samsung, sane

I got the Unified Driver (.gz) from 
http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/CLX-3185FW/XAA

I extracted the .gzip file in my home directory and took a terminal as root:

root@joost-laptop:/home/joost/cdroot/Linux# sh install.sh

The " Unified Linux Driver Installer" started and got a message: "Environment components necessary". In the 'Help Viewer' i read the message: " CUPS must be installed before Unified Linux Driver". Ubuntu software centre tells met that CUPS is installed.

The Unified Linux driver Installation wizard says it needs SANE (SANE stands for "Scanner Access Now Easy"). But my Ubuntu software centre says it is already installed. 
I took the option "Install Anyway" and it seems it installed correctly. Even printing a test page seems to function from the software point of view. Only my CLX-3185FW is not reacting. Didn't spit out anything. Anyone got 'n answer?

Comment: Please try the packages available on http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ which fully support your printer. Follow the steps *uninstallation information* (to uninstall the Samsung drivers from their website) *Setting Up the Repository* and *Selecting Packages to Install*. This repository contains slightly modified Samsung software for better integration in Ubuntu (and Debian). I really prefer package installations rather than custom vendor installers. Especially the Samsung installer isn't really elegant as you can read on other pages of the website. If this helps I'll post it as an asnwer.

Comment: Installed version 4.00.36. Now I've got a working scanner, but no printer. Preferred the other way around. For my printer(mfp CLX-3185) the table says: 3.00.65 4.00.36 Samsung MFP Xerox MFP.  Should I have taken version 3.00.65?

Comment: That means it should work for 3.x series 3.00.65 and up and for 4.x series 4.00.36 and up. So it really should just work. Now **edit** your question to include more details. "does not work" is not very descriptive. Please keep in mind that we can't see your screen and we completely rely on the information you provide in your question. So, what have you tried exactly, what happens instead? etc.

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the right metapackages? `samsungmfp-driver` should make the printer work. And again, the driver version in the table is the *minimum*. Just install the latest stable via the metapackage. Now that is `4.00.39-1` (but don't worry about that - it will install it automatically). Please include the output in your `syslog` and the CUPS logs you get about the time you send a job to the printer - it may include some hints.

Comment: I followed the four steps of "Setting Up the Repository". Downloaded v 4.00.36. Extracted in home. Installed as root in terminal. Where can i find "sumsungmfp-driver"? Don't know anything about metapackages. Hope this info helps to tell you where I'm at. tnx

Comment: installing from Ubuntu Software Centre: suld-driver-4.00.39

Comment: No need to extract files. You can install with any package management application you like after configuring the repository. The explanation about which package is in the site as well. If you need it I can write a detailed answer tomorrow.

Comment: Transitional package for suld-driver-4.00.39 (may be safely removed). "This is a dummy transitional package to reflect package renaming" says my Ubuntu Software Center. Is this a clue?

Comment: @gertvdijk it seems a detailed answer could be used for this question. If you write it I will upvote it. Thank you!